# android: Using Global Multidimensional array variable in CustomView

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, custom-view

how to get or set a Multidimensional array variable value when using a global class. tried different ways no success

my Global class

```
public  class  Global extends Application {
    private String  [][][] myarray=new String[10][10][10];
    public String[][][] getMyarray() {
        return myarray;
    }
    public void setMyarray(String[][][] myarray) {
        this.myarray = myarray;
    }
}
```

my activity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(new MyView(this));
            }

      class MyView extends View
      {
          public MyView(Context context) {
              super(context);

              final Global globalVariable = (Global) getApplicationContext();
              //set the value for myarray[2][2][1]
              (globalVariable).setMyarray[2][2][1]("me");             //<---- how?

              // get the value of myarray [2][2][1]
              final String name  = globalVariable.getMyarray[2][2][1]; //<----       how?
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I this  get from other [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5290216/Re-android-Using-Global-Multidimensional-array-var.aspx):

```
  Global myGlobal = new Global();
  String[][][] myArray = myGlobal.getMyarray(); // returns the array reference
  myArray[2][2][1] = "me";      // set the value of a single array element
  final String name  = myArray[2][2][1];
```